# Weird issue happening with recaptcha on mobile web view (Updated in more detail)

Tags: reactjs, sass, recaptcha

I know styling for recaptcha is very restricted to prevent users from affecting its purpose, but my recaptcha has an issue.

So I have the recaptcha widget in my web which looks like this:

[image]

But when I switch over to mobile view. It becomes like that

[image]

I have no idea how the `Privacy . Terms` appeared outside of the box. Tried adjusting it by resizing etc, it doesn't work.

I have the following codes:

```
.recaptcha-container {
  margin-top: 10px; 
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-left:35%;
  margin-right:50%;
  //align-items: center;
  // display: flex;
  // flex-direction: column;
  // transform: scale(1.2);
  // height:100px;
  // width:150000%;
}

// for screens 768px and below
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .recaptcha-container {
    margin-left:0;
    transform:scale(0.95);
    // transform-origin:"0 0"
    //border-radius: 5px;
  }
```

Update:
It was a zoom issue that was causing the issue. The zoom is focused on the recaptcha which I have no idea why. I also realize that is it affecting both web and mobile.

For the framework, I am using reactjs and the library that I am using from is ReCAPTCHA from 'react-google-recaptcha'

Weirdly enough, I removed most of my settings for .recaptcha-container and the zoom was stopped on the web side.

```
.recaptcha-container {
  margin-top: 30px  
 }
```

But my mobile view is still having the same error/issue:

Zoom (100%):

[image]

Zoom (75%):

[image]

Zoom (125%)

[image]

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .recaptcha-container {
    margin-left:-15px; //for the positioning I need 
    width: 304px;     
   }
}
```

I tried applying things like `user-scalable` to no, using transform-origin in the div, playing around with padding, margin, width etc it doesnt solve the issue.

Comment: try using css clipping or masking

Comment: It doesnt seem to be working

Comment: The ReCaptcha css is dusgusting and not very responsive. Trying to manipulate their css seems tidious. I would end up [making the captcha invisible](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-recaptcha#invisible-recaptcha) and [adding the text required by google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-recaptcha#hiding-the-recaptcha) to my site

Comment: The requirement for the web is classic captcha sadly